# JavaScript validation for postcode and state combined

Tags: javascript, html

When I run the code the validation on my JavaScript isn't working properly, every time I try to submit the form with the correct validation I still get an error message. The part that is not working is the postcode and state if statements it seems to skip through the validation and always end with the conclusion that there is an error. How do I fix this?

```js
"use strict";
/*get variables from form and check rules*/
function validate() {
  var errMsg = ""; /* stores the error message */
  var result = true; /* assumes no errors */
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
  var other = document.getElementById("other").checked;
  //get varibles from form and check rules here
  // if something is wrong set result = false, and concatenate error message

  var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value.split("/");
  var date = new Date(dob[2], parseInt(dob[1]) - 1, dob[0]);
  var today = new Date();
  var age = today.getFullYear() - date.getFullYear();

  if (age >= 80) { // Outside age ranges.
    errMsg = errMsg + "You must be 80 or younger to apply for this job\n";
    result = false;
  }

  if (age <= 15) { // Outside age ranges.
    errMsg = errMsg + "You must be 15 or older to apply for this job\n";
    result = false;
  }

  if (postcode.charAt(0) == 3 && state == "VIC") {
    result = true;
  } else if (postcode.charAt(0) == 8 && state == "VIC") {
    result = true;
  } else if (postcode.charAt(0) == 1 && state == "NSW") {
    result = true;
  } else if (postcode.charAt(0) == 2 && state == "NSW") {
    result = true;
  } else if (postcode.charAt(0) == 4 && state == "QLD") {
    result = true;
  } else if (postcode.charAt(0) == 9 && state == "QLD") {
    result = true;
  } else if (postcode.charAt(0) == 0 && state == "NT") {
    result = true;
  } else if (postcode.charAt(0) == 6 && state == "WA") {
    result = true;
  } else if (postcode.charAt(0) == 5 && state == "SA") {
    result = true;
  } else if (postcode.charAt(0) == 7 && state == "TAS") {
    result = true;
  } else if (postcode.charAt(0) == 0 && state == "ACT") {
    result = true;
  } else {
    errMsg = errMsg + "State and postcode do not match\n";
    result = false;
  }

  if (other) {
    errMsg = errMsg + "You have selected other skills, you must enter one other skill in the text box\n";
    result = false;
  }

  if (errMsg != "") { //only display message box if there is something to show
    alert(errMsg);
  }
  return result; //if false the information will not be sent to the server
}

function init() {

  var regForm = document.getElementById("regform"); // get ref to the HTML element

  regForm.onsubmit = validate; //register the event listener 
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Prototype Website" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript" />
  <title>The Virtual World</title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="apply.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>The Virtual World</h1>

      <nav>
        <p class="menu"><a href="index.html#home">Home</a></p>
        <p class="menu"><a href="jobs.html#jobs">Jobs</a></p>
        <p class="menu"><a href="apply.html#apply">Apply</a></p>
        <p class="menu"><a href="about.html#about">About</a></p>
        <p class="menu"><a href="enhancements.html#enhancements">Enhancements</a></p>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="required">
      <h5>All fields with * are required</h5>
    </section>
    <form id="regform" method="post" action="http://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Job Application</legend>
        <p><label for="JobID">*Job ID:</label>
          <input type="text" name="JobID" id="JobID" maxlength="5" size="10" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$" required="required" /></p>
        <section id="choose">
          <h5>Please choose from QM593 or CS197</h5>
        </section>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Personal Details</legend>
          <p><label for="title">*Title:</label>
            <select name="title" id="title" required="required">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>         
            <option value="title">Dr</option>
            <option value="title">Mr</option>
            <option value="title">Miss</option>
            <option value="title">Mrs</option>
            <option value="title">Ms</option>
         </select></p>

          <p><label for="firstName">*First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" maxlength="20" size="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" required="required" />

            <label for="familyName">*Family Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="familyName" id="familyName" maxlength="20" size="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="midName">Middle Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="midName" id="midName" maxlength="20" size="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" /></p>

          <p><label for="dob">*Date of Birth:</label>
            <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" maxlength="10" size="10" required="required" /></p>

          <p>*Gender:
            <label for="male">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" value="male" required="required" />
            <label for="female">Female</label>
            <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" value="female" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="street">*Street Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="street" id="street" maxlength="40" size="30" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="suburb">*Suburb/town:</label>
            <input type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" maxlength="40" size="20" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="state">*State:</label>
            <select name="state" id="state" required="required">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>         
            <option value="state">VIC</option>
            <option value="state">NSW</option>
            <option value="state">QLD</option>
            <option value="state">NT</option>
            <option value="state">WA</option>
            <option value="state">SA</option>
            <option value="state">TAS</option>
            <option value="state">ACT</option>
         </select></p>

          <p><label for="postcode">*Postcode:</label>
            <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" minlength="4" maxlength="4" size="10" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="email">*Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="30" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="number">*Phone number:</label>
            <input type="tel" name="number" id="number" minlength="8" maxlength="12" size="10" required="required" /></p>

          <p>Skill list:</p>
          <p><label for="C/C+">C/C+</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="C/C+" name="category[]" checked="checked" /></p>
          <p><label for="XML">XML</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="XML" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="Java">Java</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Java" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="Python">Python</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Python" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="SQL">SQL</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="SQL" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="PERL">PERL</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="PERL" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="MySQL">MySQL</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="MySQL" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="Windows">Windows</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Windows" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="UNIX">UNIX</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="UNIX" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="Linux">Linux</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Linux" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="other">Other Skills:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="category[]" /></p>
          <textarea id="other" name="other" rows="8" cols="70" placeholder="Please write any other skills you may have here..."></textarea>
          </p>
        </fieldset>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset Application" />
    </form>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: according to your code, if you result get false for age and true for postcode it will return true? yes?

Comment: yes but the age if statement does not relate to the postcode if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate ids for other checkbox and text area. fix that.
This may be working.

```js
"use strict";
/*get variables from form and check rules*/
function validate() {
  var errMsg = ""; /* stores the error message */
  var result = true; /* assumes no errors */

  var other = document.getElementById("other").checked;
  //get varibles from form and check rules here
  // if something is wrong set result = false, and concatenate error message

  var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value.split("/");
  var date = new Date(dob[2], parseInt(dob[1]) - 1, dob[0]);
  var today = new Date();
  var age = today.getFullYear() - date.getFullYear();

  if (age >= 80) { // Outside age ranges.
    errMsg = errMsg + "You must be 80 or younger to apply for this job\n";
    result = false;
  }

  if (age <= 15) { // Outside age ranges.
    errMsg = errMsg + "You must be 15 or older to apply for this job\n";
    result = false;
  }

 var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
 var state = document.getElementById("state").options[document.getElementById("state").selectedIndex].text;

 var regex;
 //VIC = 3 OR 8, NSW = 1 OR 2 ,QLD = 4 OR 9 ,NT = 0 ,WA = 6 ,SA=5 ,TAS=7 ,ACT= 0.
 switch (state) {
    case "Please Select":
        return false;
    case "VIC":
        regex = new RegExp(/(3|8)\d+/);
        break;
     case "NSW":
        regex = new RegExp(/(1|2)\d+/);
        break;
     case "QLD":
        regex = new RegExp(/(4|9)\d+/);
        break;
     case "NT":
        regex = new RegExp(/0\d+/);
        break;
     case "WA":
        regex = new RegExp(/6\d+/);
        break;
     case "SA":
        regex = new RegExp(/5\d+/);
        break;
     case "TAS":
        regex = new RegExp(/7\d+/);
        break;
     case "ACT":
        regex = new RegExp(/0\d+/);
        break;
 }
 if(!postcode.match(regex)){
   errMsg = errMsg + "State and postcode do not match\n";
   result = false;
 }

  if (other && document.getElementById("otherText").value.trim().length===0) {
    errMsg = errMsg + "You have selected other skills, you must enter one other skill in the text box\n";
    result = false;
  }

  if (errMsg != "") { //only display message box if there is something to show
    alert(errMsg);
  }
  return result; //if false the information will not be sent to the server
}

function init() {

  var regForm = document.getElementById("regform"); // get ref to the HTML element

  regForm.onsubmit = validate; //register the event listener 
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Prototype Website" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript" />
  <title>The Virtual World</title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="apply.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>The Virtual World</h1>

      <nav>
        <p class="menu"><a href="index.html#home">Home</a></p>
        <p class="menu"><a href="jobs.html#jobs">Jobs</a></p>
        <p class="menu"><a href="apply.html#apply">Apply</a></p>
        <p class="menu"><a href="about.html#about">About</a></p>
        <p class="menu"><a href="enhancements.html#enhancements">Enhancements</a></p>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="required">
      <h5>All fields with * are required</h5>
    </section>
    <form id="regform" method="post" action="http://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Job Application</legend>
        <p><label for="JobID">*Job ID:</label>
          <input type="text" name="JobID" id="JobID" maxlength="5" size="10" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$" required="required" /></p>
        <section id="choose">
          <h5>Please choose from QM593 or CS197</h5>
        </section>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Personal Details</legend>
          <p><label for="title">*Title:</label>
            <select name="title" id="title" required="required">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>         
            <option value="title">Dr</option>
            <option value="title">Mr</option>
            <option value="title">Miss</option>
            <option value="title">Mrs</option>
            <option value="title">Ms</option>
         </select></p>

          <p><label for="firstName">*First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" maxlength="20" size="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" required="required" />

            <label for="familyName">*Family Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="familyName" id="familyName" maxlength="20" size="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="midName">Middle Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="midName" id="midName" maxlength="20" size="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" /></p>

          <p><label for="dob">*Date of Birth:</label>
            <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" maxlength="10" size="10" required="required" /></p>

          <p>*Gender:
            <label for="male">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" value="male" required="required" />
            <label for="female">Female</label>
            <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" value="female" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="street">*Street Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="street" id="street" maxlength="40" size="30" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="suburb">*Suburb/town:</label>
            <input type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" maxlength="40" size="20" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="state">*State:</label>
            <select name="state" id="state" required="required">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>         
            <option value="state">VIC</option>
            <option value="state">NSW</option>
            <option value="state">QLD</option>
            <option value="state">NT</option>
            <option value="state">WA</option>
            <option value="state">SA</option>
            <option value="state">TAS</option>
            <option value="state">ACT</option>
         </select></p>

          <p><label for="postcode">*Postcode:</label>
            <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" minlength="4" maxlength="4" size="10" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="email">*Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="30" required="required" /></p>

          <p><label for="number">*Phone number:</label>
            <input type="tel" name="number" id="number" minlength="8" maxlength="12" size="10" required="required" /></p>

          <p>Skill list:</p>
          <p><label for="C/C+">C/C+</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="C/C+" name="category[]" checked="checked" /></p>
          <p><label for="XML">XML</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="XML" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="Java">Java</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Java" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="Python">Python</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Python" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="SQL">SQL</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="SQL" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="PERL">PERL</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="PERL" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="MySQL">MySQL</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="MySQL" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="Windows">Windows</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Windows" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="UNIX">UNIX</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="UNIX" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="Linux">Linux</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Linux" name="category[]" /></p>
          <p><label for="other">Other Skills:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="category[]" /></p>
          <textarea id="otherText" name="other" rows="8" cols="70" placeholder="Please write any other skills you may have here..."></textarea>
          </p>
        </fieldset>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset Application" />
    </form>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the duplicated Id's but the postcode validation still doesn't work

Comment: can you post a test case which fails the logic?

Comment: @evan run the fiddle and check now

Comment: Yep works now thank you. One more thing does the code contain any JavaScript library? I'm 90% sure that the code doesn't include any but I thought just in case I should ask if it does

Comment: no, there's no library involved. Just plain javascript